# Keras Model asks for compiling even after compile call

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a simple Keras model:

```
model_2 = Sequential()
model_2.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(500,)))
model_2.add(Dense(4))
#answer = concatenate([response, question_encoded])

model_1 = Sequential()
model_1.add(LSTM(32, dropout_U = 0.2, dropout_W = 0.2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 2048)))
model_1.add(LSTM(16, dropout_U = 0.2, dropout_W = 0.2, return_sequences=False))
#model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=False))

merged = Merge([model_1, model_2])
model = Sequential()
model.add(merged)
model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))

#model.build()

#print(model.summary(90))
print("Compiled")
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The code fails with the error when calling fit():

```
    raise RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.
```

Clearly, I have called compile. How could I resolve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you are creating 3 instances of the Sequential model but only compile the 3rd one (the merged).
It might be easier to use a different structure for a multi-modal network:

```
input_2 = Input(shape=(500,))
model_2 = Dense(32)(input_2 )
model_2 = Dense(4)(model_2)

input_1 = Input(shape=(None, 2048))
model_1 = LSTM(32, dropout_U = 0.2, dropout_W = 0.2, return_sequences=True)(input_1 )
model_1 = LSTM(16, dropout_U = 0.2, dropout_W = 0.2, return_sequences=False)(model_1)

merged = concatenate([model_2, model_1])
merged = Dense(8, activation='softmax')(merged)

model = Model(inputs=[input_2 , input_1], outputs=merged)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but i get AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'compile'

Comment: sorry, just made an edit (i forgot to paste the model step), do you still get this?

Comment: cool! ok, so this seems to be a slightly different issue; in your original post input for model 1 is (None, 2048) but in the error you have (None, None, 2048). 
If the latter is correct, then concatenating layers probably won't work as is and you will have to reshape your inputs to match dimensions. 
If it's the former, then have a look whether there is a typing error or shape error.